# Catching errors in Bash with glassfish commands [return code in pipes]

Tags: bash, glassfish, pipe

I am writing a bash script to manage deployments to a GF server for several environments. What I would like to know is how can I get the result of a GF command and then determine whether to continue or exit.

For example

Say I want to redeploy, I have this script

```
$GF_ASADMIN --port $GF_PORT redeploy --name  $EAR_FILE_NAME --keepstate=true $EAR_FILE | tee -a $LOG
```

The variables are already defined. So GF will start to redeploy and either suceed or fail. I want to check if it does and act accordingly. I have this right after it.

```
RC=$?
if [[ $RC -eq 0 ]]; 
    then echoInfo "Application Successfully redeployed!" | tee -a $LOG; 
else
    echoError "Failed to redeploy application!"
    exit 1
fi;
```

However, it doesnt really seem to work .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the *pipe*

```
$GF_ASADMIN ... | tee -a $LOG
```

`$?` reflects the return code of `tee`.

Your are looking for `PIPESTATUS`. See `man bash`:

> PIPESTATUS
>
> An  array  variable (see Arrays below) containing a list of exit
>   status values from the processes in  the  most-recently-executed
>   foreground pipeline (which may contain only a single command).

See also this example to clarify the `PIPESTATUS`

```
 false | true 
 echo ${PIPESTATUS[@]}
```

Output is: `1 0`

The corrected code is:

```
RC=${PIPESTATUS[0]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Or try using a code block redirect, for example:

```
{
  if "$GF_ASADMIN" --port $GF_PORT redeploy --name  "$EAR_FILE_NAME" --keepstate=true "$EAR_FILE"
  then
    echo Info "Application Successfully redeployed!"
  else
    echo Error "Failed to redeploy application!" >&2
    exit 1
  fi
} | tee -a "$LOG"
```